# Как решить вопрос с слайдером?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: картинка счетчика и прогрессбара]
Есть слайдер с счетчиком, при включении нижнего прогрессбара перестает работать счетчик. 
onTranslated : counter,
onTranslated : moved

либо один работает либо другой
как объединить функцию, что-то не догоняю))спасибо

```
$(".top-bg .slides-block .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    dots: false,
    nav: false,
    mouseDrag: false,
    smartSpeed: 400,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 4000,
    onInitialized  : counter,
    onTranslated : counter,
    afterInit : progressBar,
    onTranslated : moved,
    startDragging : pauseOnDragging
});

function counter(event) {
    var element   = event.target;         // DOM element, in this example .owl-carousel
    var items     = event.item.count;     // Number of items
    var item      = event.item.index + 1;     // Position of the current item
    $('.top-bg .slides-block #counter').html("<span class='item'>"+item+"</span> <span>/</span> <span class='items'>"+items+"</span>");

function moved(){
    clearTimeout(tick);
    start();
}
```

Comment: Желательно прикрепить действующий код, для этого есть сниппет или использовать codepen \ jsfiddle

Comment: да итак понятно объяснил,два раза действует onTranslated в опциях слайдера, либо один либо другой работает. как объединить две функции спрашивается или решить проблему

Comment: И так непонятно. Пример должен воспроизводить вашу ошибку и другой человек сможет потыкать и что-то поделать. А так вам поможет только тот кто сталкивался с такой проблемой в остальном это будет тыкание пальцем в небо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function counter(event) {
  var element = event.target; // DOM element, in this example .owl-carousel
  var items = event.item.count; // Number of items
  var item = event.item.index + 1; // Position of the current item
  $('.top-bg .slides-block #counter').html("<span class='item'>" + item + "</span>  <
    span > /</span > < span class = 'items' > "+items+" < /span>");
    clearTimeout(tick); start();
  }
```